# WSL command doesn't work through CMD/PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install software to multiple WSL distros, so I'm doing this using a batch file.

Here's an example command and its output:

```
CMD> wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
/bin/bash: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y: command not found
```

However, it works from inside the distro:

```
CMD> wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04
root@device-name:/mnt/d/username/Documents/tech-projects/exp/exp-py# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
[...]
```

How to fix this?

---

Full script, with my details redacted. The commands for [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer#install) and [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#debian-ubuntu-linux-raspberry-pi-os-apt) come from their respective docs; the appropriate section is linked.

```
wsl --shutdown

wsl -u root -d Debian  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
wsl -u root -d Debian  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
wsl -u root -d Debian  "apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gh git vim bat"


wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "type -p curl >/dev/null || apt-get install curl -y curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt-get/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gh git vim bat"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "curl https://pyenv.run | /bin/bash"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-16.04  "echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"


wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04  "type -p curl >/dev/null || apt-get install curl -y curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt-get/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04  "apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gh git vim bat"


wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "type -p curl >/dev/null || apt-get install curl -y curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt-get/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gh git vim bat"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "curl https://pyenv.run | /bin/bash"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-18.04  "echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> /home/username/.bashrc"


wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04  "type -p curl >/dev/null || apt-get install curl -y curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | tee /etc/apt-get/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04  "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04  "apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gh git vim bat"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the flags `--exec bash -c` worked.

Example of a full line in the shell script:

```
wsl -u root -d Ubuntu-22.04 --exec bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install curl -y"
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/1163wm0/comment/j94yu63/?context=3

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).